# How to access asp.net web services hosted on IIS in virtual machine from host application?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx, virtualization

I have some webservices hosted in a sharepoint environment on a virtual machine.  These services are accessible from within the VM, but when I try to invoke this service from my asp.net application on the host machine I get an error with status 500 and a soap fault exception (unauthorized access).  The IIS setting on both host and VM allows anonymous access.

When I try to access these services directly from the host browser i.e. IE (by typing in the URL) the service is accessible.

Any insight into these is really appreciated?

Comment: http status 500 is internal error not unauthorized.

Comment: Corrected the question. Thanks.

Comment: When you say "ASP.NET web services", you mean ASMX services, right, not WCF?

Comment: Hi John,  Yes, its asp.net web services.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to access these services from the IE, that means the services are available to the user account which runs the IE.

Try setting impersonation=true for your asp.net application, so that it runs in the logged in user account. This can be done by either changing the web.config file of your application or by IIS mmc. See the MSDN help if you cannot figure out how to set impersonation = true.

Comment: Impersonation is set to true!!

Comment: Though anonymous access is enabled, you need to specify the authentication mode in IIS. 
Setting impersonation = true and the authentication mode in IIS = Integrated Windows Authentication might help you. Go through the steps in this link http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/10917_3065031_2